# NSJSONSerialization messing up resulting NSDictionary

Tags: ios, ios7, nsdictionary, afnetworking-2, nsjsonserialization

I'm having trouble parsing the json output from a web service. I am using NSJSONSerialization to parse the output into an NSDictionary. Also using AFNetworking by subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager. For now the response serialiser is AFHTTPResponseSerializer which returns NSData
Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
```

Pretty straightforward. And the err object is nil so the conversion works fine.

BUT: the result I get straight from the web service is this:

```
           "address":
           {
               "address1": "Ivy House",
               "address2": "Sandy Lane",
               "city": "Rush",
               "postCode": null,
               "email": "notknown@whatever.com",
               "telephone": "18437584",
               "mobile": null,
               "smsAlert": null,
               "county": "Dublin",
               "country": "Ireland",
               "websiteAddress": "www.example.com"
           },
```

The result I get after printing the content of dict is this:

```
address =     {
    address1 = "Ivy House";
    address2 = "Sandy Lane";
    city = Rush;
    country = Ireland;
    county = Dublin;
    email = "notknown@whatever.com";
    mobile = "<null>";
    postCode = "<null>";
    smsAlert = "<null>";
    telephone = 18437584;
    websiteAddress = "www.example.com";
};
```

The issue is that the resulting NSDictionary does NOT have double quotes and so saving the NSDictionary to disk in plist format FAILS!

I have also tried using AFJSONResponseSerializer which returns NSDictionary but the contents are the same as above!

Where's the issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lack of double quotes in your example is only because this is how NSDictionary (or perhaps even NSString) is printed. If saving this dictionary to property list fails then it's due to another reason (which you can trace using `error` in `[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:]`.

Comment: I agree with @Andrey. It seems that NSDictionary description doesn't add quotes for strings which contain only alphanumerical chars (without separators).

Comment: @Andrey I couldn't save to a plist so I cannot try reading again. writeToURL:atomically: is returning NO even though URL is perfectly valid. Documentation says if the return is NO then it's because the dictionary is not properly formed (This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant output would not be a valid property list.)

Comment: Well you can use `dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:` to figure out the error. It has nothing to do with double quotes. I think those `nulls` might be the real reason why saving to plist fails.

Comment: I used propertyListWithData:options:format:error: and here's the error that I got: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unexpected character { at line 1) UserInfo=0x8e81b20 {NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character { at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)}

Answer (score 2):

The problem here doesn't seem to be related to double quotes at all. When printed, `NSDictionary` (as well as other Foundation objects) drop enclosing double quotes when they are not needed (e.g. when no spaces or special characters in the string).

Now, the likely problem preventing you from serialising your `NSDictionary` to a property list is presence of `nulls` in the JSON and, consequently, in `NSDictionary`. According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Property list objects include `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSDate`, and `NSNumber` objects.

Whereas `nulls` from JSON will be represented as instances of `NSNull`, thus making your `NSDictionary` an invalid Property List.

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary has different structure then JSON string. So when you parse a JSON string to NSDictionary you should not expect quotes.

You can save the JSON data and parse it again on runtime.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfilename.dat"];

 // Save it into file system
[data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I moved back to using AFHTTPResponseSerializer and the responseObject is now of NSData type. Here's my code: NSString *filePath =  [[self applicationCacheDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfilename.dat"]; BOOL save = [responseData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
save now returns YES! and I can read again the data file into an NSDictionary. So this is looks like a good workaround